# Certificate error while trying to update app in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to update an app that is registered in the App Store.

I have developed and tried to update on a different Macbook than the one I used.

I archived the project and selected the app and then the Distribute App.

And IOS App Store -> Upload -> Next ..

But the first error occurred here.

> "~~~~". has 3 iOS Distribution certificates. Contact the creator of one 
>       of these certificates to get a copy of the private key.

So I extracted the certificate from the existing computer and added it to the keychain.

I clicked Manage Certificates ... and pressed the + button, but a second error occurred.

> You have a current iOS Distribution certificate or a pending certificate request.

I added a private key and tried several methods, but ultimately failed to update the app. Please tell me how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the certificate is created on other mac then you have to import the particular certificate from the KeyChain with private key.

1. open KeyChain access -> select your certificate -> right click on it and select the Export option from the drop down.
2. select your location where you want to save the .p12 file.
3. set a password to protect your certificate and click on ok.

4.once it is created and save. just copy the certificate.p12 file and install it in your other mac.

5. Now download the provisioning profile and rebuild the project.
6. login in Xcode with same developer account you are using to upload the build and upload your build on app store.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: You have a current iOS Distribution certificate or a pending certificate request.

Apple now allow only a numbers of certificates on a single Account.